# cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data’: File exists

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, nfs

## Cluster information:

- Kubernetes version: 1.19.2
- Cloud being used: private
- Installation method: kubeadm init
- Host OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- CNI and version: Waeve Net: 2.7.0
- CRI and version: Docker: 19.03.13

After my PostgreSQL pod failed, I get the following log from the restarted pod, which keeps crashing

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data’: File exists

I mount a PV (nfs share) via a PVC in my container at the above mentioned location, to avoid data loss, if the pod fails. Am I doing something wrong?

Below is my yaml description of the sts.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-11-20T18:59:43Z"
  generation: 2
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:spec:
        f:podManagementPolicy: {}
        f:replicas: {}
        f:revisionHistoryLimit: {}
        f:selector:
          f:matchLabels:
            .: {}
            f:app: {}
        f:serviceName: {}
        f:template:
          f:metadata:
            f:labels:
              .: {}
              f:app: {}
          f:spec:
            f:containers:
              k:{"name":"postgres"}:
                .: {}
                f:envFrom: {}
                f:image: {}
                f:name: {}
                f:ports:
                  .: {}
                  k:{"containerPort":5432,"protocol":"TCP"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:containerPort: {}
                    f:protocol: {}
                f:resources: {}
                f:terminationMessagePath: {}
                f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
                f:volumeMounts:
                  .: {}
                  k:{"mountPath":"/var/lib/postgresql/data"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:mountPath: {}
                    f:name: {}
            f:dnsPolicy: {}
            f:restartPolicy: {}
            f:schedulerName: {}
            f:securityContext: {}
            f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
            f:volumes:
              .: {}
              k:{"name":"postgres-nfs"}:
                .: {}
                f:name: {}
                f:persistentVolumeClaim:
                  .: {}
                  f:claimName: {}
        f:updateStrategy:
          f:rollingUpdate:
            .: {}
            f:partition: {}
          f:type: {}
    manager: kubectl-create
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-11-20T18:59:43Z"
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:spec:
        f:template:
          f:spec:
            f:containers:
              k:{"name":"postgres"}:
                f:imagePullPolicy: {}
    manager: kubectl-edit
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-06-29T15:42:01Z"
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:collisionCount: {}
        f:currentReplicas: {}
        f:currentRevision: {}
        f:observedGeneration: {}
        f:replicas: {}
        f:updateRevision: {}
        f:updatedReplicas: {}
    manager: kube-controller-manager
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-06-30T21:54:36Z"
  name: postgres
  namespace: klos
  resourceVersion: "86776831"
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/klos/statefulsets/postgres
  uid: 89931f08-0a5d-4d9a-885b-b12bc0264c5d
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  serviceName: database
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: postgres-config
        image: postgres
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: postgres
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          name: postgres-nfs
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: postgres-nfs
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: postgres-nfs-claim
  updateStrategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      partition: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
status:
  collisionCount: 0
  currentReplicas: 1
  currentRevision: postgres-57d8d67cd5
  observedGeneration: 2
  replicas: 1
  updateRevision: postgres-57d8d67cd5
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

In another namespace, my other postgresql pods, managed by kubedb, also fail with the following error log

> I0630 22:32:14.854128       1 log.go:172] FLAG:
> --alsologtostderr="false" I0630 22:32:14.854192       1 log.go:172] FLAG: --enable-analytics="true" I0630 22:32:14.854202       1
> log.go:172] FLAG: --help="false" I0630 22:32:14.854212       1
> log.go:172] FLAG: --log-flush-frequency="5s" I0630 22:32:14.854226
> 1 log.go:172] FLAG: --log_backtrace_at=":0" I0630 22:32:14.854235
> 1 log.go:172] FLAG: --log_dir="" I0630 22:32:14.854244       1
> log.go:172] FLAG: --logtostderr="true" I0630 22:32:14.854252       1
> log.go:172] FLAG: --stderrthreshold="0" I0630 22:32:14.854267       1
> log.go:172] FLAG: --use-kubeapiserver-fqdn-for-aks="true" I0630
> 22:32:14.854274       1 log.go:172] FLAG: --v="3" I0630
> 22:32:14.854281       1 log.go:172] FLAG: --vmodule="" I0630
> 22:32:18.072864       1 log.go:172] We want "postgres-0" as our leader
> I0630 22:32:18.105157       1 leaderelection.go:217] attempting to
> acquire leader lease  postgres-ha/postgres-leader-lock... I0630
> 22:32:18.107698       1 log.go:172] Leader changed from '' to
> 'postgres-2' I0630 22:32:18.127571       1 log.go:172] Annotating pods
> for statefulset I0630 22:32:18.134472       1 log.go:172] This pod is
> now a replica I0630 22:32:18.134495       1 log.go:172] Starting
> database wrapper script as replica Running as Replica Attempting
> pg_isready on primary Attempting pg_isready on primary Attempting
> pg_isready on primary Attempting pg_isready on primary Attempting
> pg_isready on primary I0630 22:32:35.707460       1
> leaderelection.go:227] successfully acquired lease
> postgres-ha/postgres-leader-lock I0630 22:32:35.707543       1
> log.go:172] Leader changed from 'postgres-2' to 'postgres-0' I0630
> 22:32:35.707580       1 log.go:172] Got leadership, creating the
> trigger file I0630 22:32:35.808205       1 log.go:172] Annotating pods
> for statefulset I0630 22:32:35.809106       1 pod.go:56] Patching Pod
> postgres-ha/postgres-0 with
> {"metadata":{"labels":{"kubedb.com/role":"primary"}}} I0630
> 22:32:35.821348       1 pod.go:56] Patching Pod postgres-ha/postgres-2
> with {"metadata":{"labels":{"kubedb.com/role":"replica"}}} I0630
> 22:32:35.868268       1 log.go:172] This pod is now a primary Postgres
> promotion trigger_file found. Running primary run script Running as
> Primary mkdir: can't create directory '/var/pv/': Stale file handle
> rm: can't stat '/var/pv/data/*': Stale file handle chmod:
> /var/pv/data: Stale file handle The files belonging to this database
> system will be owned by user "postgres". This user must also own the
> server process.
>
> The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8". The
> default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8". The
> default text search configuration will be set to "english".
>
> Data page checksums are disabled.
>
> initdb: could not access directory "/var/pv/data": Stale file handle
> mv: can't stat '/var/pv/data/postgresql.conf': Stale file handle
> /scripts/primary/start.sh: line 48: /var/pv/data/pg_hba.conf: Stale
> file handle /scripts/primary/start.sh: line 49:
> /var/pv/data/pg_hba.conf: Stale file handle
> /scripts/primary/start.sh:
> line 50: /var/pv/data/pg_hba.conf: Stale file handle
> /scripts/primary/start.sh: line 51: /var/pv/data/pg_hba.conf: Stale
> file handle pg_ctl: could not access directory "/var/pv/data": Stale
> file handle psql: could not connect to server: No such file or
> directory     Is the server running locally and accepting     connections on
> Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
>
> /scripts/primary/start.sh: ignoring /var/initdb/*
>
> pg_ctl: could not access directory "/var/pv/data": Stale file handle
> cat: can't open '/var/pv/data/postgresql.conf': Stale file handle
> I0630 22:32:36.181192       1 log.go:172] DB Wrapper terminated,
> exiting too. If there was an error, find it below. I0630
> 22:32:36.181216       1 log.go:172] exit status 1

Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: sorry I hadn't read and thought you were using a PVC like I always do. So this NFS share is in a stale file handle state on the worker node, because the previous pod crashed but the container must still be running and the process must be inside the NFS fileshare. You need to somehow reboot that worker node or kill this container. I also bet that your pod is coming back on the same node.

Comment: @DevLounge 
After rebooting the worker node, on which the container is running, the following log appears: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/postgresql’: Stale file handle. Also rebooting the node with the nfs share does not improve anything. Deleting the container does also lead to the same log message mentioned above.